# uncaught typeerror cannot read property '0' of undefined within a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project to make a mastermind. Everything is going well except 
This is giving me following error --> uncaught typeerror cannot read property '0' of undefined.

```
    function vergelijking(computer, speler)
    {
        var arrayVergelijken = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < arrayLengte; i++)
        {
            if(computer[i] === speler[i])
            {
                arrayVergelijken.push("1");
            }
            else
            {
                arrayVergelijken.push("0");
            }
        }

        return arrayVergelijken;
    }
```

EDIT: typos 
I have made some changes to the code. It is working better then before. But there is still a strange thing. The code is giving me a '0' every time. Like when I try all the colours ( geel, groen, rood, blauw, oranje) the respons i'm getting is a zero. Normally when A colour is matching with the random colour of the computer, the code should give me a one '1'.

EDIT: I have made some changes and now the program is doing great. It does everything that I wanted from it. Happy :) --> http://pastebin.com/VJWj3uc3

Comment: Either you typed the name of one of the arrays incorrectly or it doesn't exist at all, or it doesn't have any values in it.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Can you include that code?

Comment: `arrayLengte` is undefined as well (in this code), but the error seems to be thrown for `computer[i]` or `speler[i]`. You should provide working examples (as in "showing the error") that we can actually execute.

Comment: I have put my code on pastebin --> http://pastebin.com/xDjHGJuE
Keep in mind that everything is in dutch (sorry about that)

Comment: in your function `juisteAntwoorden()` you're calling `vergelijking()` with no arguments. it expects 2 arguments which are arrays (`computer`, `speler`). That is why you're getting the undefined error.

Comment: I see. But my thoughts there were:

if you execute --> function vergelijking(computer, speler). It should return an array (return arrayVergelijken)

So i would like to get this array in: function juisteantwoorden()
Thats why I did --> var array = vergelijking().

How can I put the array from vergelijking() in var array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your [script](http://jsbin.com/IRugami/1/edit) little updated and translated to English. Sorry, I do not know Dutch :-)

Some notes:

you are calling `Math.random(kleuren)`. It should be `Math.random()`

Error: you called `juisteAntwoorden()` without parameter. It should be array. Changed.

Reason why you always got 0s: you compared string "0" or "1" from array with 0 or 1 using `===`. Changed to parseInt(array[i])

Game never stops: while loop: `||` changed to `&&`

And I left there `console.log` messages.

Comment: The || change to && was very good. Ty for that. I fixed the code and now i give parameters with juisteAntwoorden().
I added the "" around the 1 and 0, this is helping a lot.

Ty for this good advise!!